# Retrieve Images from network drive

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i have 3 servers, inside one(server1), there is a folder with images (D:\images), i want to be able to read those images from server2 and server3.

i network mapped the drive in those 2 servers (letter "Z").

i was hopping to be able to do something like this in the asp net code behind:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("Z:\image1.bmp")) Then
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com")
        End If
```

is it possible to do this ?

Comment: you don't need to map a drive letter. just use a UNC path: `\\server\share\image1.bmp`

Comment: i was trying to use a map drive because i did not want to show the server ip

Comment: show the ip how? the paths are used inside your code exclusively and never visible to the users. what makes you think the users would have a `Z:` drive that maps to your server? if I send you `c:\users\marc\documents\seekrit bank information`, do you think that'd exist on your c: as well?

Comment: if i use that path (your first comment) it shows C:\... an  I need to use Z:\